# CSS Slide Down and Slide Up on document click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a issue here. I'm trying to do the slideUp and slideDown equivalent in CSS3 transitions but also want when document is clicked the div element slides up.

**Here is the code**
http://jsfiddle.net/RK8FZ/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="search-content">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search"/>
      <input type="submit" />
   </div>
   <section class="wrapper">
      <span id="toggle-search">Search</span>
   </section>
</div>
```

**Here is the CSS code**

```
#main #search-content { position: relative; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: all .3s linear; background: #FFF; opacity: 0;}
#main #search-content.open { max-height: 200px; opacity: 1; }
```

**Here is the jquery code**

```
    function toggleSearch() {

    $('#toggle-search').on('click', function(event){
        $('#search-content').toggleClass('open').find('input[type="search"]').focus();
        $(this).text( $(this).text() === "Search" ? "Close" : "Search" ); 
    })

    $('#search-content').on ('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).on('click', function() {
        if( $('#search-content').hasClass('open') ) {
            $('#search-content').removeClass('open');
        }
    });

}
```

Can anyone figure this thing out? What it is happening is that it triggers the open and the close at the same instante.

Comment: rather than using `if( $(this).addClass('search-open') )` try `if( $(this).hasClass('open') )`

Comment: can you add your HTML please? :)

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for it...

Comment: Here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/RK8FZ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/RK8FZ/8/)

I guess this is what you need

```
    $(function () {
        toggleSearch();
    })

    function toggleSearch() {

        $('#toggle-search').on('click', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('#search-content').toggleClass('open').find('input[type="search"]').focus();
            $(this).text($(this).text() === "Search" ? "Close" : "Search");
        })


    }
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        $('#toggle-search').text('Close');
        $('#search-content').removeClass('open');
    });
$('#search-content').on('click', function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: not exactly.. that part i'd figured out. What i want is when i click outside my search-content div, it slides up

Comment: @carlosjgsousa I have update the demo and code above please check it and respond.

Comment: now the problem is when you click the input it triggers the slideup as well.

Comment: yeah thats  it ... hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).addClass('search-open')) {
        $('#search-content').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

What are you checking in if condition? If you wan to check if search-open class exists then you can use

```
    if ($(.search-open').length > 0)
```